# Convert string to smallint

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have radiobutton (for male and female check) The problem I am getting error if I try to convert the string(Sex) to the database(smallint)

Here is my code:

```
public class MakeAppointment
{
    private MakeApptEntities newAppointment = new MakeApptEntities();

    public void add( string FirstName, string LastName,  string Sex) {

    tbl_MakeAppointment_MA nAppt = new tbl_MakeAppointment_MA();
    tbl_PatientDetails_PD pDetails = new tbl_PatientDetails_PD(); 

    pDetails.PD_FirstName = FirstName;
    pDetails.PD_LastName = LastName;
    pDetails.PD_Sex = Convert.ToInt16(Sex);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: `string Sex`, sounds like fun...

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting an "Input string was not in a correct format" error.  What's the value of `Sex` when you debug?  Also, include the call to the method so we can see how you're sending in `Sex`

Answer (score 0):

Normally for something like this I like to use `enum` since EF now supports enums. In case you cannot change the model and DB schema, you can create an extension method that would do your conversion for you. Try something like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Int16 ToDbValue(this string sex)
    {
        switch (sex.ToLower())
        {
            case "male":
                return 0;
            case "female":
                return 1;
            default:
                // throw exception, or return what you want as default
         }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in your `add` method:

```
pDetails.PD_Sex = sex.ToDbValue();
```

NOTE: change the values in the `switch/case` above to correspond to the values you use.

Make sure this class is visible from your `MakeAppointments` class. Easiest way would be to put the code in the same file. If you think you'd be using `ToDbValue` method elsewhere, create a separate file for this class and make sure it's in the same name space as `MakeAppointments`.

Comment: I am getting confused now with the variable sex in lower case! I can use it in this line of code: pDetails.PD_Sex = sex.ToDbValue();

Comment: Sorry I mean I can't use it

Comment: Yes you can still do `pDetails.PD_Sex = Sex.ToDbValue();` the lowercase version is just local to the extension method

Answer (score 0):

Use Int16.Parse instead of convert.toInt16: 
pDetails.PD_Sex = Int16.Parse(sex);

*Using enumeration type for constants is also a very good idea!

---

Dear Asghraf, I think the problem is somewhere else, I'm pretty sure about Int16.Parse. check the value of input parameters and trace your program by putting breakpoints.
Look at the following link about converting string to number too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sedigheh.. I have tried both solutions but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did change PD_Sex data type in database from tiny int to int and now working fine with Int32.Parse(Sex) Many thanks everybody for support